# How to code custom 404 error handling?

Tags: 7, bootstrapping

I was planning on using a new domain name when migrating my legacy site to Drupal. I already have the php script that will translate old urls into Drupal Urls (I'm not using pathauto for that).

Now there is a chance I have to keep showing content on the old domain (mainly for SEO purposes). This site won't have any login or write-backs at all, it basically just shows the content and link to the new site.

How would I intercept the 404's that Drupal would now generate, preferably at a very low bootstrap level since there could be tons of invalid requests?

**Update:**

Sounds like I could use hook_boot() to intercept every page request early and then have the query string parsed and redirected to the matching node/... page on the same site.

Or, similar to Fast404 I could add an include_once to settings.php and do the redirect there:

```
include_once('.sites/default/modules/myredirect_module/myredirect_module.inc');
```

Will there be a big difference between those two options?

Comment: Do you know http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect and http://drupal.org/project/redirect? They're the best solution to what you're trying to do.

Comment: [path_redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) is 6 only - OP is using 7.  Also, I think [redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) is called later in the bootstrap process, whereas @MotoTribe wants to intercept it as early as possible.

Comment: If I correctly understood, there is content that is still shown from the legacy site, and Drupal needs to redirect to that; if that is the case, may you shown an example of URL that should be redirected to the legacy site? It is to understand if it is possible to make a string comparison, or it is required to call some Drupal function, including functions exposed from third-party modules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just use the [Fast404](http://drupal.org/project/fast_404) module (if I'm understanding your question correctly).

> Drupal has expensive 404 errors. On an 'average' site with an
>   'average' module load, you can be looking at 60-100MB of memory being
>   consumed on your server to deliver a 404. Consider a page with a bad
>   .gif link and a missing .css file. That page will generate 2 404s
>   along with the actual load of the page. You are most likely looking at
>   180MB of memory to server that page rather than the 60MB it should
>   take.
>
> That's where Fast 404 comes in. This module combines a very common
>   method of handling missing image/file 404 errors (discussed here and
>   planned for Drupal 8) with a method created by dpardo (a co-maintainer
>   of this project) to deliver super fast 404 error pages for both
>   missing images and bad paths. Depending on which method of
>   implementation you choose (aggressive or super aggressive) you can
>   deliver 404 errors using less than 1MB of memory on your server.

Answer (score 5):

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_init() {
  if(!menu_get_item($_GET['q'])) {
    //do whatever you want if page not found
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I think hook_boot() would work in my case since it would happen earlier in the bootstrap process.

Comment: @MotoTribe `menu_get_item()` would not be accessible from `hook_boot()`.