# Search Engine returning multiple 404s, Redirect 404 urls based on node id in the url

Tags: 7, .htaccess

I am using Drupal 7. Many of my url paths (up to 6,000) have moved to new url paths with no 301 redirect so they are returning lots of 404s on google. i have paths like /articles/bla/bla-bla/12345 which moved to /articles/bla-new/something/12345

Since the old path which now returns a 404 has the node id in the url at the end, i want to redirect a path like this `"/articles/bla/bla-bla/12345"` to `node/12345` once the system detects a 404

Any suggestions for using .htaccess redirect rules or other module to achieve this?

I've tried this: `RewriteRule ^articles/*/+ node/+ [R=301,L]` but it doesnt look right.

I need some help. thank you in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^articles/.*/.*/(.*)$ /node/$1 [R=301,L]
```

of not worked use your absolute URL

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^articles/.*/.*/(.*)$ http://www.yourdomin.com/node/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Does the code above have a rule to detect if the url returned a 404? Thank you

Comment: @ITProManager No, I don't write rule, do you want I add it or you can ? I just redirect what you need.

Comment: yes i would like the rewrite only when the page returns a 404, not for every url, can you include some code or expression for that? thank you

Comment: @ITProManager I update the answer ,try that.

Comment: Thank you for the codes above. I tried them both, the first one didnt work, it rewrites all pages to the web server root (/public_html/drupal_root/node/node_id) while the second code rewrites all pages to node/node_id. I would like it to trigger for only urls that return 404 error pages, not all pages. any suggestions? thank you

Comment: @ITProManager the first rule needs to have a slash in front of `node/$1` like `/node/$1` otherwise it will expand it to the file system as oppose to web path. Secondly, I don't think you can detect a 404 at .htaccess level, since this all happens before the application receives your request and sends a 404 response. The only option sounds like for you to write a `hook_init` and detect if there's going to be a 404 response, parse the URL and do a redirect yourself. See [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/24963/5284) for the basics

Comment: @Beebee 404 could be detect simply on .htaccess  something like `RedirectMatch 404 ^/path/.*$` works fine, but the problem is conditional  404 detections. as you said and I agree with that  using hook_init is another good solution for this question.

Comment: @ITProManager do you want to redirect all `404` to that path or only the articles `404`?

Comment: @zhilevan i would like to know how to redirect all nodes that return error codes to their node/node_id as well, but for now articles are the ones having the issues for me for now. so an answer that returns all 404 nodes to their node/node_id is acceptable for me as well. thank you